# Does AdomdDataReader work with queries with no columns?

Tags: mdx, data-warehouse, adomd.net

I'm currently trying to switch from using CellSet to using AdomdDataReader for a project, because I noticed that performance is significantly better with the latter.

So far it works great, with one exception: Queries that don't specify any columns will make the DataReader return false on the very first Read() call, implying that there are no rows to read.

Example 1 (can't be read via DataReader):

```
SELECT
{ } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Some].[Dimension].[Here] } ON ROWS
FROM CubeName
```

Example 2 (can be read via DataReader):

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Dummy] AS NULL
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Dummy] } ON COLUMNS,
{ [Some].[Dimension].[Here] } ON ROWS
FROM CubeName
```

Example 1 doesn't work via AdomdDataReader (no rows), but works via CellSet and via SSMS and MDX Studio. Example 2 is a workaround that I'd like to avoid. 
Is there any way to get this to work via AdomdDataReader or is this a known limitation?

/Edit: It turns out that the AdomdDataReader also skips columns that show only the [All] member of a dimension. Via CellSet (and via SSMS or MDX Studio), these columns are displayed, though.